# aws fargate ECS not able to use the wait command in a docker CMD

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

Using `Docker` and `docker-compose` locally, the following works:

1. `docker-compose.yml` contains image and build definitions, as well as args, for each individual container (of which there are eight), e.g:

```yaml
        App1:
                image: app1
                build:
                        context: ./APP1
                        args:
                                SERVICE_NAME: APP1
                        dockerfile: Dockerfile
                ports:
                        - "8001:8001" # java debug ports
                restart: unless-stopped
```

etc.

2. `Dockerfile` is the same across all eight, as follows:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:21.0.1_12-jdk
ARG SERVICE_NAME
ARG APP_DIR=/opt/app
RUN mkdir -p ${APP_DIR}
COPY ${SERVICE_NAME}.sh ${APP_DIR}
COPY dependencies ${APP_DIR}/dependencies
COPY ${SERVICE_NAME}.jar ${APP_DIR}
COPY ${SERVICE_NAME}.local.properties ${APP_DIR}

USER root

RUN chmod -R 777 ${APP_DIR}

# When the container starts, run the startup script
ENV SERVICESCRIPT=${APP_DIR}/${SERVICE_NAME}.sh
CMD exec $SERVICESCRIPT
```

3. Each application has its own .sh script which controls startup, in a way similar to the following and using an approach suggested [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

nohup java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8001 $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dspring.profiles.active=docker -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -jar /opt/app/APP1.jar /opt/app/APP1.local.properties > /opt/app/APP1.log &
wait -n
exit $?
```

This works fine, when I run using `docker-compose up` locally.

Now, I want to port this to Fargate. I have done this using the following changes:

1. Update the docker-compose to use the image name containing the ECR repo.
2. Change `local.properties` to `awstest.properties` (so that I am using the correct external endpoints etc)
3. use `docker-compose push` to push the images to the ECR repo.

I then configured a fargate task definition and a service to run the application on Fargate, but the containers won't start up. The exception I see in Cloudwatch is as follows:

```
2024-02-22T12:06:07.141+00:00   /opt/app/APP1.sh: 1: : not found

2024-02-22T12:06:07.141+00:00   /opt/app/APP1.sh: 2: wait: Illegal option -n
```

Why would this fail on AWS when it works locally?

Comment: I don't understand the point of that script. Why run a program with `nohup` to send it to the background, and then just wait for that program to exit? Why not remove the `nohup` and the `wait` and just run the Java program directly?

Comment: I'd also wonder if the `: not found` message is the symptom of a script with DOS newlines.

Comment: @MarkB I was just following the style set by the docker docs I linked. Happy to accept a suggestion for a better script. DavidMaze I'll check, thanks - but I have created and edited only in vi so I doubt it

Comment: @DavidMaze that turned out to be the issue - fixing that resolved both problems. Feel free to write up an answer that I can accept

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the page that suggests running a docker application with `nohup` and `wait` like that if you would link to it.

Comment: It's in the question - https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be new lines in the file were in Windows format rather than linux. Changing the line endings resolved the issue